Correctly handle rate limit sleep time in Github
I am writing a script to archive github repos using PyGithub.
    token = os.environ["GITHUB_TOKEN"]

    g = github.Github(auth=github.Auth.Token(token))
    repos = []
    for reponame in repos:
        try:
            repo = g.get_repo(f"{org_name}/{reponame}")
            repo.edit(archived=True)
        except UnknownObjectException:
            pass
        except RateLimitExceededException:
            print("Rate limited")
            time.sleep(g.rate_limiting_resettime - time.time())
            break

Once a rate limit is reached I want to break out of the for loop, sleep until the rate limit is reset and then continue the loop again. How do I do that?
I know I can get the sleep time using g.rate_limiting_resettime - time.time()
https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/github.html#github.MainClass.Github.rate_limiting_resettime

You know how long you want to sleep, so why not just sleep for that long?

This question is similar to: In Python, how can I put a thread to sleep until a specific time?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Woodford specifically I'm asking how to break and continue again with the loop after sleeping. It's already in the question. The question you linked is not the same

You aren't calling sleep in your code so it's not clear at all what your problem is if not that. Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: How to ask a good question

@Woodford Added.

Using a for loop here is cumbersome because sometimes you want to retry the same repo if you get rate limited. You also don't want to archive the same repo at the beginning of the list over and over if you restart from scratch. Best here is to keep track of which repo you're processing by index and advance to the next one only once it's processed without error.
repo_idx = 0
while repo_idx < len(repos):
    reponame = repos[repo_idx]
    try:
        repo = g.get_repo(f"{org_name}/{reponame}")
        repo.edit(archived=True)
    except UnknownObjectException:
        pass
    except RateLimitExceededException:
        print("Rate limited")
        time.sleep(g.rate_limiting_resettime - time.time())
        continue  # try this repo again from the top
    repo_idx += 1  # no error, so go to the next repo

Consider adding an extra few seconds to your sleep time as a safety buffer from getting rate limited again right away.
